# link to login does not work, in ASP.NET Core Identity UI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have configured my asp.net core 2.2 application to scaffold identity(so I can customise its appearance) based on this [Scaffold Identity in ASP.NET Core projects=>Create full identity UI source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio) link. 
The http://localhost:12345/identity/account/login url works when I request it directly in the browser, but it does not work when i incude it as a link on the home page. 
What am I doing wrong?

**Startup.cs:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
                //.AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2).
                AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
            {
                options.AllowAreas = true;
                options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Identity", "/Account/Manage");
                options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaPage("Identity", "/Account/Logout");
            });
            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = $"/Identity/Account/Login";
                options.LogoutPath = $"/Identity/Account/Logout";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = $"/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
            });
            services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
        }
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error", "?code={0}");
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

**_Layout.cshtml:** link to login in the home page's layout.

```
<a asp-page="/identity/account/login" 
class="btn btn-sm btn-white btn-icon rounded-pill d-none d-lg-inline-flex"
data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left">
<span class="btn-inner--icon"><i class="fas fa-sign-in"></i></span>
<span class="btn-inner--text">Login</span>
</a>
```

Comment: I suggest that open up developer tools and look at the actual URL being requested. Just to make sure it is actually the same URL

Comment: Hello @darkonekt, it is the home page url. In fact clicking on every identity based url on the home page(register, login, forget password etc) goes back to the home page.

Comment: Yeah the home page can be anywhere in the site.... And you are setting these in the Layout not in the home page...   Anyways try this: <a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">

Comment: May be setting the area will help.  Also use your developer tools F12 to see the network request... you will be able to see the actual url being requested.  It is the only way to be sure.

Comment: Remember the Layout can be called from any page or view in the site... This will effectively change the URLS declared within it.

Comment: Thank you @Darkonekt, adding the asp-area and updating the asp-page fixed the issue.

Comment: You go it. Nice!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There're two ways to do that.

Approach 1: using the `href`

```
<a href="/identity/account/login" 
    class="btn btn-sm btn-white btn-icon rounded-pill d-none d-lg-inline-flex"
    data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left">
    <span class="btn-inner--icon"><i class="fas fa-sign-in"></i></span>
    <span class="btn-inner--text">Login</span>
</a>
```

Approach 2:

```
<a asp-area="Identity"  asp-page="/Account/Login" 
    class="btn btn-sm btn-white btn-icon rounded-pill d-none d-lg-inline-flex"
    data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left">
    <span class="btn-inner--icon"><i class="fas fa-sign-in"></i></span>
    <span class="btn-inner--text">Login</span>
</a>
```